# Where did my ArrayList Go? Metro app

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime

In my Windows 8 app written using Visual Studio 11 Express Beta, I cannot use the ArrayList.    Here is my code:

```
using System.Collections;


ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
```

Compiler error:

> The type or namespace name 'ArrayList' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Is this something new?  I love ArrayLists :)

Comment: "The .NET Framework class library contains several new generic collection classes in the System.Collections.Generic namespace. These should be used whenever possible instead of classes such as ArrayList in the System.Collections namespace." http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx

Comment: Your code can only get better by not using ArrayLists.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For WinRT, they took out all of the non-generic collections - it's faster and makes your code more reliable.  Use List<T> instead.

ps... this will not be your last time saying "why the heck did they take away that API?" while migrating to WinRT

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

Considering documentation of [ArrayList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.collections.arraylist%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), it's available till 4.0 version. 
Check your project version of .NET Framework. Considering that you're writing for Metro, it has to be 4.5 (at least).

More details can see on this post:

[How to use ArrayList class in metro style class library project?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/da/winappswithcsharp/thread/469bb6cf-662e-43d6-84ae-119784bd9c9a)

And [System.Collections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh454064%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) namespace for Metro Style applications **lacks** of `ArrayList` type.

Comment: +1 tomorrow as I've hit the daily vote cap! Tag me in this post tomorrow to remind me :)

Answer (score 1):

ArrayList is not available in .NET 4.5 for metro style apps. Use the generic version of List, if you need an object list, use `List<object>`.

For the .NET for metro style apps API reference, take a look here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh454064%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can't use an `ArrayList` in a WinRT app, you'll have to use a `List`.

Comment: `ArrayList` is not available for MetroStyle applciations in `System.Collections` namepsace.

Comment: @Tigran check my answer again :)

Comment: In what namespace are you finding ArrayList?  I agree with Tigran, it's not in any of the ones in my environment.

Comment: @DRAirey1 You can't use `ArrayList` in a WinRT app as my answer states :). You have to use `List`

Comment: Sorry, I understand what you're saying now.  I'd edit your response though to reference the generic List<Object>.  'List' is a different animal.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on .NET Framework version that you are using. ArrayList is not supported in .Net 4.5.1.  you should use the generic form of List, `List<T>`  instead of `ArrayList` as the collection types.

Take a look here:

[Is List<Object> a good replacement for ArrayList?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22570189/is-listobject-a-good-replacement-for-arraylist)

and you can learn more here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/41107z8a.aspx