# Is List<Object> a good replacement for ArrayList?

Tags: c#, arraylist, .net-3.5, generic-list, .net-4.5

`ArrayList`, which I use in legacy Compact Framework code, does not seem to be available in newfangled (.NET 4.5.1) code.

I am storing instances of custom classes in it.

What is a good replacement for it - `List<Object>`, or is there something more suitable?

Comment: We have generics now. Why not refactor the code to use `List<CustomClass>`?

Comment: C# is a statically typed language. It is strongly recommended that your Data Model is as close to the reality as possible. This means that if you need to represent a list of integer numbers, use a `List<int>`. If you need a list of dogs, use a `List<Dog>`. If you need a list of "whatevers", use a `List<Whatever>`. Untyped, pre-generics practices (which date back to .Net 1.1) where everything is `object` or "stringly typed" are strongly discouraged in C# in general.

Comment: agree generic is the right way to work on .NET

Comment: @HighCore why you typed good answer as comment? There is not much point to copy-paste yours as answer and nothing for OP ta accept :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @HighCore mentioned in his comment, you should use the generic form of List, `List<T>`. If you have several classes defined that you need to include in that List, they probably have common properties, methods. In that case, you can make an `abstract` class for the group of classes.

`List<Object>` is a possible replacement, but not a good one.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `List<object>` is a good *replacement* for `ArrayList`.

If you want to have a list type that can store *anything*, you can use either `ArrayList` or `List<object>` as the collection type. It will have the same performance and behavior characteristics.

The question is this: Why are you using `ArrayList` to begin with? If you're coming from a pre-generics version of .NET, then you probably have no choice. You either have strongly typed arrays (which are constant in size) or you have `ArrayList` which is dynamic in size but overly "generic" in type. It can store anything.

Now, with the new .NET and C# versions, it's time to let all that go.

*(regarding comments about "net .NET and C# version": obviously "new" here is not new as in 2014-new, but compared to whatever textbook or sourcecode the OP has learned from generics is "new" compared to using `ArrayList`.)*

You want your collections to be strongly typed. It makes your life easier since you know what fields/properties/members are available on the items of the collection etc.

As such, what you want to do is to figure out what the *base* type of your elements are, and make the collection a `List<BaseType>` or similar, this will make your life a whole lot easier.

If you're storing a bunch of integers, use `List<int>`. If you're storing a bunch of strings, use `List<string>`. If you're storing a bunch of objects of type `SomeCustomObject`, use `List<SomeCustomObject`.

Comment: It's important to remark that *"new .Net and C# versions"* is not quite accurate, because Generics have been with us since C# 2.0, which dates back to 2006. So it's not really "new".

Comment: Which begs the question, *why ArrayList to begin with?* I'm assuming pre-generic textbook.